# How to find all numbers that contain a subset of digits

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of numbers, and I'd like to find all the numbers that contain subset of digits

For example:

```
column A
34523423
43243444
3443243
342323
342345
3445454
5345365
```

Given the list above, I want to find all numbers that contain the subset `44`.  If there's a match the number should be copied to column B.
So, in this example, column B should contain

```
43243444
3443243
3445454
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub find_numb()

Dim i as integer 
Dim j as integer 

i = 1
j = 1

'Cells(6, 12) will contain the number that I am looking up

look_up = Cells(6, 12)

Do While i < 605

If InStr(look_up, Cells(i, 1)) Then
    Cells(j,2) = Cells(i, 1)
    j = j + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

This results in only the same number, for example if my input is 43 and in my list are 43 and 4443, then the output is only 43.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged it as [tag:vba] but I see no VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kinda swapped the *InStr* argument so try this:

```
Do While i < 605
    If InStr(Cells(i, 1), look_up) <> 0 Then
        Cells(j,2) = Cells(i, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```